# JPQL: sort queryresult by "best matches" possible?

Tags: jpa, pattern-matching, jpql

I have the following question/problem:

I'm using JPQL (JPA 2.0 and eclipselink) and I wanna create a query that gives me the results sorted the following way:
At first the results sorted ascending by the best matches. After that should appear the inferior matches. 
My objects are based on a simple class called 'Person' with the attributes:

```
{String Id,
String forename,
String name}
```

For example if I'm searching for "Picol" the result should look like:

```
[{129, Picol, Newman}, {23, Johnny, Picol},{454, Picolori, Newta}, {4774, Picolatus, Larimus}...]
```

PS: I already thought about using two queries, the first is searching with "equals" and the second with "like", although I'm not quite sure how to connect both queryresults...?

Hope for your help and thanks in advance,
Florian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If, as your question seem to imply, you only have two groups (first group : forename or name equals searched string; second group : forename or name contains searched string), and if all the persons of a given group have the same "match score", then using two queries is indeed a good solution.

First query :

```
select p from Person p where p.foreName = :param or p.name = :param
```

Second query :

```
select p from Person p where (p.foreName like :paramSurroundedWithPercent 
                              or p.name like :paramSurroundedWithPercent)
                             and p.foreName != :param 
                             and p.name != :param
```

Execute both queries (each returning a `List<Person>`), and add all the elements of the second list to the first one (using the `addAll()` method)

Comment: This solution seems already pretty interesting (thank you!) but is there a way to combine both queries to one? Because I'm using the query for filling an endless list on my mobile client app, which means that I'm always giving a 'startindex'(.setFirstResult) and 'count'(.setMaxResults) variable to the query.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't see a solution to do this in a single query in HQL. You could do it in SQL using a union.

Comment: I'm not quite sure whether I got it right, so you mean I simply create a 'nativeQuery' with a SQL-statement instead of using JPQL because this can't use the 'union'-command?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. Since union removes duplicate values, you don't even need the two last clauses of the second query.

Comment: Do you have already a page with good examples of such a union-use for sql? Hoped I could get around the native stuff ;)